# Null Pointer Exception in setter of entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, setter, one-to-one

I am trying to map one-to-one relation between User and ProteinData Entity but getting null pointer exception in setter in My User Entity.

My main service code **Program.java**

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String a[]){


        Session session=HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        User user=new User();
        user.addHistory(new UserHistory(new Date(),"set name to akku"));
        user.setName("akku");
        user.getProteinData().setTotal(234);



        user.addHistory(new UserHistory(new Date(),"set goal to 234"));
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.beginTransaction();




        User loadedeUser=(User)session.get(User.class,1);

        System.out.println(loadedeUser.getName());

        System.out.println(loadedeUser.getProteinData().getGoal());

        for(UserHistory history:loadedeUser.getHistory()){
            //System.out.println("key is: "+ history.getKey());
            System.out.println(history.getEntryTime().toString()+" "+history.getEntry());
        }

        loadedeUser.getProteinData().setTotal(loadedeUser.getProteinData().getTotal()+50);
        loadedeUser.addHistory(new UserHistory(new Date(),"added 32 proteins"));

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
        HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

**User Entity**

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;


    private ProteinData proteinData;

    private List<UserHistory> history=new ArrayList<UserHistory>();

    public User(){

        setProteinData(new ProteinData());
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public ProteinData getProteinData() {
        return proteinData;
    }


  public void setProteinData(ProteinData proteinData) {
        this.proteinData = proteinData;
        try{

        proteinData.setUser(this);  //Null Pointer Exception here

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List<UserHistory> getHistory() {
        return history;
    }
    public void setHistory(List<UserHistory> history) {
        this.history = history;
    }

    public void addHistory(UserHistory historyItem){

        historyItem.setUser(this);

        history.add(historyItem);
    }

}
```

**ProteinData class**

```
 public class ProteinData {

        private int id;
        private User user;
        private int total;
        private int goal;

        public int getTotal() {
            return total;
        }
        public void setTotal(int total) {
            this.total = total;
        }
        public int getGoal() {
            return goal;
        }
        public void setGoal(int goal) {
            this.goal = goal;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }
        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }
    }
```

I have created a setter for setting value of  `proteinData` variable in User but on passing `proteinData.addUser(this)` through my setter i am getting a null pointer exception

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: May be the proteinData itself null and hence cause NPE whenever you try to parse proteinData object. Check whether your proteinData is loaded and is not null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and setters are called by Hibernate during entity lifecycle, so it isn't guaranteed that this setter won't be called with `null` value. To avoid this error simply check if the parameter is null

```
  public void setProteinData(ProteinData proteinData) {
      this.proteinData = proteinData;
      if (proteinData != null) {
          proteinData.setUser(this);
      }
  }
```

Comment: On what getter? In `getProteinData()` you only have `return proteinData;`, you can't get a null pointer there. Maybe you should update the question with service code, how are you creating your entities.

Comment: updated my question, getting null pointer  at line `System.out.println(loadedeUser.getProteinData().getGoal());` in my Program.java on following your instruction.

Comment: You need to debug this yourself, and try to narrow down the issue. For example, after you save the user with `session.save()`, did you check if `proteinData` is also saved in the database? Are you sure the id is `1` (since it is hard coded in line `User loadedeUser=(User)session.get(User.class,1);`). To avoid that at least, try with `Serializable id = session.save(user);` and then `User loadedeUser=(User)session.get(User.class, id);`. At this point, you need to give us more debugging info so we can help you.

Comment: thank you very very much, passing serializable id did the trick but i was passing id 1 which is present in my db then why it was giving exception,Any idea??

Comment: Probably some earlier record which had no `proteinData`. Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because the protein data object has to be initialized before you call the setter method. Hope this helps